# Persisting dates between FullCalendar and an index view

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

I'm working on a website, asp.net MVC kind of thing. On the home page, I have two alternate views. One is a jquery FullCalendar, and one is an index view, both displaying events from a database.

I can currently change the month being viewed in either, but I want to be able to link them up, so that for example changing to view april 2013 in the calendar and then clicking "index view" will take me to april 2013 in the index view, rather than the default.

My "GetEventsForCalendar" method is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult GetEventsForCalendar(long start, long end)
{
    var startDateTime = start.ToDateTime();
    var endDateTime = end.ToDateTime();
    var listOfEvents = eventRepository.List.Where(e => e.ToDate >= startDateTime
                                                           && e.FromDate <= endDateTime).ToList()                                             .Select(eventSerialiser.SerialiseForFullCalendarJS);

    return Json(listOfEvents);
}
```

But I can't find anywhere in the codebase where it is given these parameters. The only place the function is specified is in the calendar partial view scrips section:

```
@section scripts {
@Scripts.Render(Links.Bundles.Scripts.calendar)
@Scripts.Render(Links.Bundles.Scripts.events_calendar)
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        SohoHouse.EventsCalendar.setup("@Url.Action(MVC.Events.GetEventsForCalendar())");
    })
</script>
```

}

I think the details of the month being viewed are persisted in a cookie, but I'm not sure how to access this from my index view.

If you need any other code then please ask, I'm very new to programming and stack overflow so I'm still not sure how to ask questions well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working in the end: abandoned the idea of a seperate view for the index, and instead used the jquery to create a table with a list view of the events. Then used a button to toggle between the two. For reference, the calander.js looked something like this:

```
    var report = $("#report");
    var calendar = $("#calendar .fc-content");
    report.hide();

    $("#toggle-view").click(function() {
        calendar.toggle();
        report.toggle();
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("render");
        updateToggleButtonText();
    });

    function updateToggleButtonText() {
        $("#toggle-view").text(report.is(":visible") ? "View Calendar" : "View List");
    }

    function setUpCalendar() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            events: {
                url: getEventsUrl,
                type: "POST",
                eventDataTransform: addReportRow
            },
            timeFormat: "H:mm{ - H:mm}",
            allDayDefault: false,
            eventBorderColor: "gray",
            header: {
                left: "prev,next",
                center: "title",
                right: null
            },
            weekMode: "variable",
            loading: function(isLoading) {
                if (isLoading) {
                    $("table#report > tbody:last").empty();
                }
            },
            allDaySlot: false
        });
    }

    function addReportRow(data) {
        var calendarMonth = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getDate").getMonth();
        var startDate = new Date(data.start);
        var endDate = new Date(data.end);
        if (startDate.getMonth() > calendarMonth || endDate.getMonth() < calendarMonth) {
            return null;
        }
        var tableDetails = [
            data.title,
            $.fullCalendar.formatDate(startDate, "dd MMMM yyyy"),
            $.fullCalendar.formatDate(endDate, "dd MMMM yyyy"),
            data.published ? "Published" : "Not Published"
        ];
        var row = $("<tr></tr>");
        for (var i = 0; i < tableDetails.length; i++) {
            row.append($("<td></td>").text(tableDetails[i]));
        }
        $("table#report > tbody:last").append(row);
        return data;
    }

    function gotoDateFromCookie() {
        var calendarDate = $.cookie("calendarDate");
        if (calendarDate !== null && calendarDate !== "Invalid Date") {
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar("gotoDate", new Date(calendarDate));
            $.cookie("calendarDate", null);
        }
    }

    function storeDateAsCookie() {
        var calendarDate = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getDate");
        $.cookie("calendarDate", calendarDate);
    }

    window.eventDropdownChanged = function() {
        location.reload();
    };
};
```